# How to do a Contact Form on The Index Page with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, contact-form

I want to do a Contact form on the final of a Index website like this:
[startbootstrap-freelancer](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/)

What do I need to do for this work in the Index page(not in the routes contacts/index)? I put the 'require Contact' on the Index page?
Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: please take a look at my answer. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `_form.html.erb` partial inside your `contacts` folder and insert it wherever you want.

Your form could be:

```
<%= form_for( Contact.new, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }  ) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control input-sm", placeholder: 'Name' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :subject, class: "form-control input-sm", placeholder: 'Subject' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_area :message, class: "form-control input-sm", placeholder: 'Message' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

And you could insert it inside your index with:

```
<%= render "contacts/form" %>
```